# How to compare nested array elements with each other and count the total sub documents?

Tags: mongodb

my mongodb document set look like this

```
 { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59093a8e1104a53169"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-05-03T02:03:58.249+0000"), 
    "phone" : "0000000000", 
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com", 
    "dob" : "12/26/1976", 
    "password" : "*******", 
    "stripeID" : "***", 
    "picture" : "htt://g", 
    "name" : {
        "first" : "P", 
        "last" : "e"
            },  
    "addresses" : [
        {
            "description" : "237 S ABCD, USA", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59093bsaaudua"), 
            "loc" : [
                -008.2478742, 
                124.0517012
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "apartment" : "", 
            "description" : "787 S Defghsvd  USA", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a26b77dfhgswj"), 
            "loc" : [
                -18.01, 
                34.039058
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "13210 hdsg sdjhf 90284, USA", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d2482basasas17be1"), 
            "loc" : [
                -18.01, 
                -18.01
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

what i need to do is compare loc[0] with loc[1] if addresses exists in the document and know how many of them has this x === y. i don't know how to approach this. any help would be great. thanks in advance.

i.e. what i want is in all the documents if any user has equal loc array element's,  then i want to find those documents. my query should return like:

```
{
                "description" : "13210 hdsg sdjhf 90284, USA", 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d2482basasas17be1"), 
                "loc" : [
                    -18.01, 
                    -18.01
                ]
            }
```

Comment: please update your question with an actual sample document from your collection and also mention the expected result as json. also to clarify, you want to know how many addresses that have the same value for array element 0 and 1? also do you want to know the count per document or for all documents in the collection?

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ i have updated my question please have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$addresses'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$addresses.loc", 0] },
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$addresses.loc", 1] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$addresses"
      }
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YRnbPm-qfe6

if you also want the count, you can do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$addresses'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$addresses.loc", 0] },
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$addresses.loc", 1] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$addresses"
      }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            addresses: {
                $push: '$$ROOT'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kqi4J7f-4go

Comment: i am getting an error as Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 40324 (Location40324): 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$replaceWith'' on server ds031167.mlab.com:31167. 
can you guide me why i am getting so

Comment: @Avinash replacewith is only available in v4.2 or newer. if your db version is older, you can use [replaceroot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot).

Comment: my mongodb version is  3.6.12 and replacing $relacewith with $replaceRoot  gives an error as  'expected an object as specification for $replaceRoot stage, got string' on server ds031167.mlab.com:31167.  thanks for helping out

Comment: @Avinash updated my answer with replaceRoot. also check the associated mongoplaygrounds.

Comment: @ Đĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ thanks for updating but this query is not giving the desired result it is giving empty result

Comment: @Avinash are you issuing the command against the correct collection in your db? if you look at the mongoplayground you'll see that the query works perfectly.